# How can i make this grid in css?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I'm trying to make a grid template like this picture. any idea how to do it?
[the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Edsh.png)

Also, I don't want rounded borders, I and also no gap between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be `CSS-Grid`.

As you haven't provided any attemp and proberly lack research efford for such simple task, I will not explain you how the snippet below works but refer you to some resoruces:

[Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
[MDN WebDocs Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}


/* for styling purpose only */

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 40vh;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  min-height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Alternativly you could also use `Flexox`

[Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
[MDN WebDocs Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 100%;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 80%;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 20%;
}


/* for styling purpose only */
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 40vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  min-height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```